# How to implement an Erlang function that returns N-th element of the list?

Tags: recursion, erlang

I need a little help with this:

> Write a function lists1:nth(N, L) which returns the N:th element of the list L.
>
> So the result of list call look like this:
>
> 1> lists1:nth(3, [2, 3, 4, 5]).
>
> 4

Comment: issue the title must not contain lyrics like "hello", but must rather describe the problem itself or task

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @mrjoe. It's your first question and so far the reception wasn't too good (voted -3 as of this comment). That's most likely because you didn't phrase it as a question and put a lot of unrelated, personal information. I've suggested some edits to improve it. Hope it will help you do it better next time.

Comment: Also you should provide information about yours steps for solving such question and show code with attempt getting solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at the code of the `lists` module, the principle is rather simple:

- if you have to pick the first element, just do it,

  > `nth(1,[H|_]) -> H;`
- else if N is an integer bigger than 1, remove the first element of the list and pick the (N-1).

  > `nth(N,[_|T]) when is_integer(N), N > 1 -> nth(N-1,T).`

in any other case, let's fail.

Comment: Ty, I started learning few days ago and it's like a bunch of new stuff at once so I am a little confused :)

Comment: The easiest way to design a recursive procedure is to express, in natural language, what you want to do, for example: *I know how to find the first element in a list, so, in order to find the Nth element in list, I remove the first of the list and look for the  N-1 in the remaining list, until I have to find the first element.*